# how to use remote camera when using caffe ssd?

Tags: python, camera, caffe, solid-state-drive

as the question described in the title, I have tried to use caffe ssd to detect things.https://github.com/weiliu89/caffe/blob/ssd/examples/ssd/ssd_pascal_webcam.py  the link is the project that I cloned and used.  When I tried to use webcam to do the real time analysis, I found that in the project, only the usb camera can be used to do the task, but I want to use another camera on the other server(for example the camera port is aaa@10.131.234.12:334), how can I rewrite this code so that I can use the remote camera ? thx

Answer (score 0):

To minimize changes in caffe code you can keep the web address in `video_file` and set `device_id` to something other than `0`. To add this support edit https://github.com/weiliu89/caffe/blob/ssd/src/caffe/layers/video_data_layer.cpp file by replacing line 45-47 with:

```
// suppose 101 is the code for remote webcam
if(device_id == 101){
    CHECK(video_data_param.has_video_file()) << "Must provide webcam address";
    const string& video_file = video_data_param.video_file();
    if (!cap_.open(video_file)) {
        LOG(FATAL) << "Failed to open remote webcam: " << video_file;
    }
}else {
    if (!cap_.open(device_id)) {
        LOG(FATAL) << "Failed to open webcam: " << device_id;
    }
}
```

Now rebuild caffe. Edit your https://github.com/weiliu89/caffe/blob/ssd/examples/ssd/ssd_pascal_webcam.py file line 117 like:

```
video_data_param = {
    'video_type': P.VideoData.WEBCAM,
    'device_id': 101,
    'skip_frames': skip_frames,
    'video_file': "remote webcam address"
}
```

Note: for remote webcam you might need to build `opencv` with `ffmpeg`.

Comment: thank you so much. since I met a lot of trouble on building caffe. So I decided just to edit the ssd_pascal_video.py according to your answer.I edited my ssd_pascal_video.py by chaning the video_file to my remote camera address rtsp://admin:aaa@10.131.234.12:334. and I was testing it , don't know if it works

Comment: you mean by changing `'video_type': P.VideoData.VIDEO`? There are some other things that are done for that.